# How do I render a string as razor?

Tags: c#, xml, razor, .net-core, tag-helpers

Effectively, I want to take an XML string, utilize the power of Tag Helpers representing the XML tags, and have it render the XML.

I can make Tag Helpers easily enough to generate what I want, but I can't seem to find a way to render an XML string as Razor so the Tag Helpers will work.

Comment: i'm still a little confused with what you're trying to do.  just render he xml as a string?

Comment: Show us what you have tried and what isn't working. Remember to add a [mcve]